# Middle clicking on account name should open profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed

Middle clicking on the account name in the top navigation bar should open the profile page (in a new tab). Since the pull down menu was introduced today, middle clicking does not do anything anymore.

Comment: There was support for middle-clicking on the account name before? I had no idea. I don't think I even have a mouse with a middle-click button.

Comment: Also Ctrl-click.

Comment: Also, clicking my name should take me directly to my account...and not open the pop-up menu (which I love btw.).

Comment: @Cody, middle-clicking is a browser feature for normal links (which often open a link in a new tab or window then, often also offered through some modifier key like Ctrl, Option or Command). So, the issue was just that the account name no longer was a normal link, but some JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of the popup is now a *hover*, clicking is a normal link that will take you to your profile (mobile users included).

Answer (score 2):

Well, they've changed it from a link to a popup menu. And as far as I can tell, the middle click works only for *links*. (Can't say I like the change, though. I used to middle-click, too.)